# Expression for Finite Blaschke Products

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, blaschke-products

We know that every proper analytic map from the unit disk to itself is a finite Blaschke product, *i.e.*
$$f(z) = e^{i\theta}\prod_{i=1}^n \dfrac{z - a_i}{1 - \bar{a_i}z}$$
for some $\theta$ and some $a_i \in \Delta$, where the $a_i$ are the zeros.

Is it true that for all $n$, there exist $A, B \in \text{Aut}(\Delta)$ such that
$$f(z) = A(p(B(z)))$$
where $p(z) = z^n$?
If not, for what $n$ does this hold?